# mysql no indexes after copying ibd file

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql (Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64) on centos 8.

I have copied an ibd file from one server to another server as following:
(same version of mysql, and same OS)

1. Create the table with the same structure.
2. Run ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;
3. Copy the ibd file to table_name.ibd in the target location
4. Run ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE

The table has indexes, but no primary key.
After copying the ibd file, the file sizes are same in two servers.

The table has no problem in the new server, but there is no indexes.
"Show indexes from table_name" has no results.

Do I miss something for coping ibd file?

Comment: [FLUSH TABLE .. FOR EXPORT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-tables-for-export-with-list)

Comment: thank you. I resolved this.

Comment: @eajeong - How did you resolve it?  With Dan's FLUSH?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes, from the  server, "flush table <table name> for export" first. It will generate *.cfg file which contains tables's schema info for INNODB engine. You have to copy *.cfg and *.ibd together. And do step 3.